# python iterating over dictionaries

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries.I'm iterating over it one inside the other.
I want to select the next item each time it iterates inside the inner loop rather than from the beginning.

```
dict1={'a':1 , 'b':2 , 'c':3}
dict2={'x':10, 'y':20, 'z':30}

for key,value in dict1:
   #do something
    for k,v in dict2:
          #do something
```

When key='a', it iterates over inner loop and does some action according to the code in that loop.Suppose that it action that it selected was 'x' in dict2.
Now when I have to iterate with key='b', I want the iteration for the inner loop to start from 'y' because 'x' was already selected.

Comment: So basically you want to step through both at the same time?

Comment: The keys in a dict are unordered. Any key in `dict1` may be paired with any key in `dict2`.

Comment: Are both dictionaries the same length?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, `for key,value in dict1` doesn't do what you want—it just iterates over the *keys*. If you want to iterate over key-value pair, you need `for key, value in dict1.items()`.

Meanwhile, it sounds like what you're asking for is lock-step iteration, not nested iteration? If so, you want the `zip` function:

```
for (k1, v1), (k2, v2) in zip(dict1.items(), dict2.items()):
    # do something
```

But note that the ordering this gives you will actually be arbitrary, because the ordering of dicts is inherently arbitrary. So, if you're happy with `('a', 'x')`, then `('b', 'y')`, etc., and *also* happy with `('a', 'y')`, then `('b', 'x')`, then `zip` is what you want. If not, it isn't.

(If you expected your `dict`s to have some inherent order, such as order of insertion, or sorted order, or anything else, you will have to use a different class. For example, `collections.OrderedDict` acts like a dictionary, but maintains the insertion order.)

---

If you want something more complicated, where you move the iteration over `dict2` programmatically in a way you can't express in a one-liner, you can always use the [iteration protocol](http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html#iterators) manually:

```
iter2 = iter(dict2.items())
for k1, v1 in dict1.items():
    k2, v2 = next(iter2)
    # do something
    # maybe do another k2, v2 = next(iter2)
    # maybe restart iter2 = iter(dict2.items())
    # and so on
```

As the docs explain, when `next(iter2)` gets to the end, it will raise `StopIteration`. What if you don't want that? Maybe you want to, as you suggested in a comment, start over again? You can solve that by catching `StopIteration`, or by using the two-argument form of `next` and checking for a sentinel. For example:

```
try:
    k2, v2 = next(iter2)
except StopIteration:
    iter2 = iter(dict2.items())
    k2, v2 = next(iter2)
```

Or you can even write a circular iteration wrapper:

```
def circular_iterate(iterable_factory):
    while True:
        yield from iterable_factory():
```

In Python 3.2 or earlier, you have to replace the `yield from` with an inner loop:

```
def circular_iterate(iterable_factory):
    while True:
        for value in iterable_factory():
            yield value
```

And now:

```
iter2 = circular_iterate(dict2.items) # note, not dict2.items()
```

---

If you're trying to track more than just a "current position", you probably need an additional data structure. For example, if you want to skip over all keys seen so far, use a `set` of keys seen so far, or a `set` of keys not seen:

```
seen_items_2 = set()
for k1, v1 in dict1.items():
    for k2, v2 in dict2.items():
        if k2 in seen_items_2:
            continue
        seen_items_2.add(k2)
        # do something
```

Comment: I have already made the dictionary OrderedDict.Just the outer one

Comment: I think this will solve the problem.I was wondering if next(iter2) will go bak to start if it hits the end of the dictionary

Comment: @Nikhil: No, `next(iter2)` will raise a `StopIteration` if it hits the end; I'll explain how to do what you want, and add links so you can figure this out for yourself (sorry for forgetting them); give me a sec to edit the answer.